# Creation Synonym among different db schemas

Tags: oracle, schema, synonyms

might seem a stupid question, but I'm pretty new to the db world.
Is that a good practice to have two oracle schemas which have synonyms pointing to each other ?

- like SCHEMA_A owns a SYNONYM_1 pointing to the TABLE_1 in the SCHEMA_B
- and the SCHEMA_B owns a SYNONYM_2 pointing to the TABLE_2 in the SCHEMA_A

Apparently technically is possible, but is that a good practice ? Does not sound as a kind of circular reference if you compare this to the "Software modules" concept ?

Thanks in advance for your responses.

Answer (score 0):

`SYNONYMs` are more like "soft links" (Linux) and "shortcuts" (Windows)

"circular reference" would be if `SCHEMA_A.TABLE_2`  was actually a synonym to `SCHEMA_B.SYNONYM_2`

As far as the synonyms in each schema pointing to each other objects...I'd definitely look at it in a questionable manner.

"Software modules" sounds more like what `PACKAGEs` do.